# Open FTP server on client side on button click

Tags: ftp

I am developing a web application. 
If a user clicks on a button on the web page, then FTP server should be open in windows explorer and the user should be able to paste files on the server.

Please help me out......

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you are developing on PHP? instead of connecting to FTP perhaps you can try a php based file manager which opens upon user's click.

Below link provides good free file managers that allow users to manage files (alike on FTP) directly on the web, and it also will allow you to add protection on file level.

http://devsnippets.com/article/7-free-powerful-file-managers.html

on another note you can hardcode a link to the ftp to contain the username and password
note that most browsers do not open on windows explorer and you won't really have control on that through web. I definitely suggest the above instead.

xtp://username@name.ext will prompt for password 
xtp://username:password@name.ext will transmit password witb no security